# Raising Errors on Failed Validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation

Please check out the code

#### HTML Code:

```
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" >
<p id='p1'></p> 

Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="fname" >

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate_form();" >
```

#### Validation Code:

```
function validate_form()
{
    if ( document.form.fname.value == "" )
    {
        $('#p1').val("Please fill in fname");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I created a form in which there are two textboxes (fname,lname). Now suppose I kept textbox1 vacant and then I press tab to go on next textbox.As I move to second textbox, on the right side of textbox1 a error message should be displayed (plz fill fname box)

Plz check the coading and correct it..My code is not displayed here proeprly..how to copy - paste code here so that it can be visible proerly..I am new so plz...

Comment: Frankly, I regret editing this.

Comment: Chacha102, I think I edited over you. My apologies.

Comment: No, I just wish I hadn't done it. Mainly because I wish the OP would have actually taken a few seconds to read how to post stuff on SO.

Comment: And I regret looking at the revision history...

Comment: Ah. I agree. Deepak, please commit more time and energy to properly communicating your problem, and neatly presenting your code.

Comment: i am soory sir...i assure u that in future these kind of mistakes will not be repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event you're looking to trigger on is called 'blur' and can be hooked up like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="javascript:validate_form();" />
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#fname').blur(validate_form);
});
```

Now the 'validate_form' function will be hooked in to the "blur" action on your fname field.

To post code on StackOverflow highlight the code portions of your questions and answers and click the button labeled "101010" to block it as code.

Also see theraccoonbear's comment on using .html() instead of .val().

EDIT: Added jQuery version and kept old input for up-voters.

Comment: I like jQuery. It really makes it much easier to separate my HTML from my Javascript. That way the HTML isn't loaded with Javascript commands.

Comment: Definitely.  It's all I use at work and I encourage everyone I work with to pick it up as well.  JavaScript is actually fun now.

Answer (score 0):

Cryo mentioned that you want the onblur event, but I think you'd also need to modify the code that sets the error message to use the html() and not the val() method in jQuery.  e.g.

```
$('#p1').html("Please fill in fname");
```

Answer (score 0):

> onclick="return validate_form();" >

Don't put form validation code on submit-onclick. It belongs on form-onsubmit. That way you're guaranteed the code will be called however the form is submitted.

> if ( document.form.fname.value == "" )

You have an `id` on that control, might as well use `document.getElementById('fname')`, or, since you appear to be using jQuery, `$('#fname').val()`. Either of those is unambiguous, which accessing inputs directly from the `document` and `form` objects may not be.

> $('#p1').val("Please fill in fname");

`val()` is for form fields not text content. You want `.text('message')`.